# Adding / appending list of strings to list of strings

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of coin pairs that I need to combine with a string, then a list of intervals.

`coins_list = ['btcusdt', 'ethusdt']`

Combine with string:

```
kline_string = "@kline_"
coins_list = [s + kline_string for s in coins_list]
```

Result:
`coins_list = ['btcusdt@kline_', 'ethusdt@kline_']`

So far so good...
The last step is where I'm getting stuck.
I need to add each list item from

`k_interval_list = ['1m', '5m', '15m']`

to each item in the previous list.

Result I'm looking for:

`['btcusdt@kline_1m', 'ethusdt@kline_1m,'btcusdt@kline_5m', 'ethusdt@kline_5m,'btcusdt@kline_15m', 'ethusdt@kline_15m,]'`

Attempt:

```
for coin in coins_list:
    for k in k_interval_list:
        stream_list = [coin + k for coin in coins_list]
```

The incorrect result is:

```
stream_list = ['btcusdt@kline_15m', 'ethusdt@kline_15m']
```

It's only adding the last item from `k_list_interval`

How do I get it to add each of the `k_list_interval` strings?

Comment: `[x + y for y in k_interval_list for x in coins_list]`

Comment: You Champion! Thank you. I knew I'd seen that before but couldn't work out what I was looking for.